# How do I include XML files in an Android build?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a few XML files I want to include in a build of my game, and I want to have access to those XML files in Android. How to I store and load those XML files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You load XML files just like you would any other asset file. Review [the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html) to learn about loading resources at runtime. Likely the easiest strategy will be to use Resource Folders:

> To put anything into a Resource Folder, you simply create a new folder
>   inside the Project View, and name the folder “Resources”. You can have
>   multiple Resource Folders organized differently in your Project.
>   Whenever you want to load an asset from one of these folders, you call
>   [Resources.Load()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)

An example of how you might use this to load an XML file:

```
TextAsset textAsset = (TextAsset) Resources.Load("MyXMLFile");  
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument ();
xmldoc.LoadXml ( textAsset.text );
```